# How can I exit a running task in C#?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I want to do something like this in C#

```
public static async Task<int> Method1()
{
    int count = 0;
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            // Do Stuff
            if (something wrong) Exit task here.
            count += 1;
        }
    });
    return count;
}
```

If something goes wrong I want to terminate the task.
How can I do that?

Comment: Maybe `if (somethinggoeswrong) return;` ???

Comment: use [CancellationToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken?view=net-8.0)

Comment: @derpirscher Unfortunately it's not that simple.

Comment: @KingVoodoo what do you mean? Clearly the task will finish once the action is finished with `return` ... If you need additional steps done after cancelling the task you should state that in your question.

Comment: Or do you mean the "outer" Task? If yes, you should also state that in your question

Comment: @derpirscher You can't just use **return** it doesn't work.

Comment: Why? How does (with your code) a `return` within the loop's body differ from just running through the whole loop (other than not doing all loop iterations). There is nothing done after the loop, there is nothing returned from this inner task. I don't see why a `return` wouldn't work or behave any different, except if there is something else you need to be done in case of error you don't mention here ...

Comment: @derpirscher You are quite right. I obviously did something wrong when I did this. I got an error message telling me i could not return a void. I tried it now and it works fine, don't know what i did wrong before. I haven't changed the code.  
Thanks.

Comment: You probably did that `return` in the scope of the enclosing method, which returns a `Task<int>` and therefore requires something to be returned from it ...

Answer (score 3):

You could consider a cancellation token and task run
In this example, we pass a `CancellationToken` to the method, which allows us to cancel the task if something goes wrong. We then pass the `cancellationToken` to the `Task.Run` method, which allows the task to be cancelled if requested. - (task run is not in the example)

```
public static async Task<int> Method1(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    int count = 0;
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            // Do Stuff
            if (something wrong) 
            {
                // Cancel the task
  cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }
            count += 1;
        }
    }, cancellationToken);
    return count;
}
```

links for further reading

CancellationToken: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken?view=net-6.0

Task.Run: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=net-6.0

Comment: Thanks, but It doesn't work for me, the task continues after cancellationToken.Throw...

Comment: and you did the task.run in another part of your script?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Task.Run is started in **Method1**.
There will never be a cancellation request from anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Just throw an uncaught exception, this will end the task and bring it to `IsFaulted` state.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1?view=net-8.0

```
if (something wrong) throw new InvalidOperationException("failed to reticulate splines");
```

Answer (score 1):

Best solution is to use CancellationToken.

```
public static async Task<int> Test(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var result= 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        // your code
        result++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

now use its :

```
 var cancellationToken= new CancellationTokenSource();
 var testTask=Test(cancellationToken.Token);
```

if need to cancel task , can use :

```
cancellationToken.Cancel();
```

if need to result of test method , can use :

```
awaite testTask;
```

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of `async`/`await` is that you can write asynchronous code very similarly to synchronous code.

So, let's turn this around:

> If something goes wrong I want to terminate the task. How can I do that?

In the synchronous world, this would be:

> If something goes wrong I want to terminate the loop. How can I do that?

And the original synchronous code would look like this:

```
public static int Method1()
{
  int count = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  {
    // Do Stuff
    if (something wrong)
      Exit task here.
    count += 1;
  }
  return count;
}
```

The answer in the synchronous world is "throw an exception" (preferred) or "return early" (unusual), e.g.:

```
public static int Method1()
{
  int count = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  {
    // Do Stuff
    if (something wrong)
      throw new InvalidOperationException("something wrong");
    count += 1;
  }
  return count;
}
```

or, less commonly:

```
public static int Method1()
{
  int count = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  {
    // Do Stuff
    if (something wrong)
      return count;
    count += 1;
  }
  return count;
}
```

Similarly, in the asynchronous world, the answer is "throw an exception" (preferred) or "return early" (unusual):

```
public static int Method1()
{
  int count = 0;
  await Task.Run(() =>
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
      // Do Stuff
      if (something wrong)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("something wrong");
      count += 1;
    }
  });
  return count;
}
```

or, less commonly:

```
public static int Method1()
{
  int count = 0;
  await Task.Run(() =>
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
      // Do Stuff
      if (something wrong)
        return;
      count += 1;
    }
  });
  return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `break;` You'll exit a for-loop that way.
 `return 0;` works too if you want to exit the whole function.

Additionally, you can also put the function in a try-catch statement, in case a crash happens, the crash will be caught in the catch() section.